# Mostrar botones

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

Tengo una tabla en la cual se llena con un foreach y en en una columna muestra botones de eliminar o editar esa fila

```
@foreach($clock as $r)
            <tr class="text-center {{ ($r->hours > 480) ? 'bg-warning-soft' : '' }} {{ ($r->hours < 480) ? 'bg-danger-soft' : '' }}">
                <td class="text-left">{{ $r->employee->Name.' '.$r->employee->LastName }}</td>
                <td>{{ $r->inDate }}</td>
                <td>{{ $r->inTime }}</td>
                <td>{{ $r->outDate }}</td>
                <td>{{ $r->outTime }}</td>
                <td width="25%" class="text-center">
                    @if(Auth::user()->groupId == 1)
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"
                                onclick="modalForm('{{ url('/editClock/'.$r['id']) }}', 'Editar marcación');"
                                title="Editar"><img src="img/icons/edit.png"/></button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-sm"
                                onclick="modalForm('{{ url('/showClockActivity/'.$r['id']) }}', 'Ver Actividades', true);"
                                title="Actividades"><img src="img/icons/doc.png"/></button>
                    @else
                        <button type="button" style="display: none" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"
                                onclick="modalForm('{{ url('/editClock/'.$r['id']) }}', 'Editar marcación');"
                                title="Editar"><img src="img/icons/edit.png"/></button>
                        <button type="button" style="display: none" class="btn btn-info btn-sm"
                                onclick="modalForm('{{ url('/showClockActivity/'.$r['id']) }}', 'Ver Actividades', true);"
                                title="Actividades"><img src="img/icons/doc.png"/></button>
                    @endif
                </td>
            </tr>
        @endforeach
```

Con el if valido la columna para mostrar los botones si es administrador debe mostrarse los botones para editar sus propios registros y los de los demas, si es supervisor debe mostrarse los botones para editar los registros de los demas y ocultarse para editar sus propios registros

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**El problema que tengo es que quiero que si entro con el supervisor "Usuario Test" no deberia mostrarme los botones para ese registro pero si para los demas registros**

EL requerimiento es: El supervisor pueder editar o eliminar los registros excepto sus propios registros

Comment: ¿Y cuál es el problema que tienes? Edita tu pregunta para ver como se te puede echar la mano.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes 3 roles, validas para admin con en el if, asi que el "else" queda para supervisores y resto de personas, tienes que hacer un "else if" para ellos, si entiendo bien tu problema